# Why setting file position and writing in it, fill with null char in C?

Tags: c, file, text

I was trying to write in a arbitrary position in a text file in C.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void write_in_file(FILE *file, char *str, fpos_t *pos){
    fsetpos(file, pos);
    for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
       fputc(str[i],file);
            }
}

int main(){

    char *str = "Hola123 Mundo\n";
    FILE *file = fopen("database/file_1.txt", "w");

    fpos_t pos = 1;
    write_in_file(file, str, &pos);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

and that text file has previous information in it. I first write `"Hola123 Mundo\n"` with `pos = 0`, and then rewrite with `pos = 1`. I was expected the output file to be

```
HHola123 Mundo
```

but a got

```
'\0'Hola123 Mundo
```

I know the first byte is a null character because in binary is `00` in the hex editor.

My intuition was that when open with `"w"` mode, rewrite the entire file, so skipping the first position result in skipping a `00` byte. Then I tried `"w+"` mode, but had the same error.

Comment: Opening a file with mode `"w"` or `"w+"` will not retain previous information. It destroys an old file and creates a new one. You would need `"r+"`. Don't use intuition, but the man page.

Comment: `#include <stdlib>`? That doesn't look like C. Also, `fpos_t pos = 1;` is dubious. Even if `fpos_t` is some kind of integer on your system (it isn't on mine), there is no guarantee that there is a simple mapping between values of `fpos_t` and offsets in the file. I recommend `fseek`, and opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: The C standard does not specify what values in the `fpos_t` type mean except that those returned by the `fgetpos` function can be used with the `fsetpos` function to reposition the stream. And it does not specify what the behavior is when you use `fsetpos` with a position not provided by `fgetpos`. C 2018 7.21.9.3 2 says the `fpos_t` passed to `fsetpos` “shall be a value obtained from an earlier successful call to the `fgetpos` function…” The behavior of setting `fpos_t` to 1 and passing it to `fsetpos` is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane the change of the mode fix my problem. thanks.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI is C, but I paste it wrong. I'm reading the C11 Standard and fseek in binary mode seems like a good choice for 8-bits char, but not for wide char. For wide char, what would you recommend?

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks. In my machine, fpos_t is a long long and fgetpos() return the column in a text file, so I used fgetpos/fsetpos to navigate through the file, but for postability, I think that I would have to use ftell/fseek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters:
`fpos_t` is an opaque type. The only correct way to use `fpos_t` is to use a value previously obtained via `fgetpos()`. If you want to set a file to a fixed offset, use `fseek()` instead:

```
void write_in_file(FILE *file, char *str, long pos) {
    fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        fputc(str[i], file);
    }
}
```

Furthermore you could use `fputs()` instead of a loop:

```
void write_in_file(FILE *file, char *str, long pos) {
    fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
    fputs(str, file);
}
```

---

To answer the original question, you never wrote your string to your file at an offset of 0 after opening the file, and opening the file with the `"w"` mode truncates the file to 0 length, deleting any data already there. When you write with an offset of 1 to an empty file, the first byte is non-deterministic and in your case was set to a 0.

If you did:

```
write_in_file(file, str, 0);
write_in_file(file, str, 1);
```

Or (Provided your file already started with `H`):

```
FILE *file = fopen("database/file_1.txt", "r+");
```

Instead of just:

```
// fpos_t pos = 1;
// write_in_file(file, str, &pos);
write_in_file(file, str, 1);
```

And:

```
FILE *file = fopen("database/file_1.txt", "w");
```

Respectively, then your file would contain:

```
HHola123 Mundo
```

Comment: On Unix/POSIX systems, gaps in a file are filled (explicitly) with zero bytes — it isn't indeterminate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is Unix/POSIX, but what does the C Standard say?

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I fix my problem changing the mode as you said and starting to use ftell/fseek for portability between machines.

Comment: AFAICS, the C11 standard does not specify what is read from a file position which was never written to (even though space further into the file was written).  Consequently, in standard C, the value for such bytes is not specified (effectively indeterminate).  I'm not even sure that the C standard recognizes the possibility of seeking beyond the current end-of-file and writing data — there are weasel words aplenty that may mean that it is undefined behaviour to try.  My comment remains accurate; your observation that some non-Unix/non-POSIX systems may exhibit different behaviour is valid too.

Comment: The standard lists lots of possible behaviours, such as trailing spaces before a newline being deleted on output, binary files having arbitrary numbers of null bytes after the last data written, difficulties associated with multibyte character sets, seeking in text files, and so on.  This reflects the diversity of systems in the world which the standard tries to accommodate.  POSIX is more restrictive; it imposes requirements that Standard C does not (and carefully marks such extensions when defining the behaviour of functions).

Comment: And, for completeness, the POSIX [`read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)
function specifies: _The `read()` function reads data previously written to a file. If any portion of a regular file prior to the end-of-file has not been written, `read()` shall return bytes with value 0._. This prevents information leakage.  In practice, I doubt that there are many (any) systems where previously unwritten bytes are read as anything other than zero bytes.